# Can't make sense of the way javascript's regex works

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does this code ([here's the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ijihaw/5/edit)):

```
var text = "T: 01202 870738";

var regex1 = /T: (.*)/;
var matches1 = text.match(regex1);

for(var i = 0; i < matches1.length; i++) {
  log("[" + i + "]: " + matches1[i]);
}
```

logs this:

```
[0]: T: 01202 870738
[1]: 01202 870738
```

and this code (note I've added the `g` option):

```
var regex2 = /T: (.*)/g;
var matches2 = text.match(regex2);

for(var i = 0; i < matches2.length; i++) {
  log("[" + i + "]: " + matches2[i]);
}
```

logs this:

```
[0]: T: 01202 870738
```

I actually don't even understand why is the first code logging `01202 870738` as the second match. How is that a match for `/T: (.*)/` if it doesn't include a `T:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is a global regular expression, so the array returned is a list of all the matches for the expression in the string. The first one isn’t, so it’s a list of groups, like you would get from `exec`. (Group zero being the entire match, and group one being the only parenthesized... group.)

Comment: Bonus question: How do you get a list of lists of groups, like the OP is semi-apparently expecting?

Comment: @cHao: `exec` in a loop or `replace`, I suppose? `replace` is fun: `var result = []; text.replace(regex2, function() { result.push.apply(result, arguments); });`

Answer (score 1):

What throws you off is the different behavior you get from a regex with and without the `g` flag. Calling `String.match` with a `g` flagged regex will return an array of all instances of the pattern within the `String` object. For example, the expression:

`"Hello World!".match(/l/g);`

Will return this array:

`["l", "l", "l"]`

However, calling the same function without the `g` flag will return an array whose first element is the matched pattern. Any element thereafter will match each expression within parentheses. For example, the expression:

`"Hello World!".match(/(Hell)o World(!)/);`

Will conveniently return this array:

`["Hello World!", "Hell", "!"]`